# Make asp button Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How can i make the asp:Button drag and drop? 
How do I get the coordinate of button after using jquery drag and drop? I want to save the coordinate to a database, so that next time I visit, the item will be in that position. For example, x : 400px, y : 800px?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record where the jquery drag-and-drop module leaves your button then you could add an event to your javascript that is fired on the 'stop' event & then call a web service to save the details:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

```
<script>
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
          stop: function() {
            ... call web service to record current object & coords in database
          }
        });
</script>

    <div id="draggable"><asp:button ... /></div>
```

... and when you reload the page you need to retrieve the coords for this object before you render (and then position the object correctly).

Comment: @amelin thanks for your reply but i had already tried this code..this code does not make a button drag.for example i had place 1 asp:button in this div and tried to move it.it vll work fine but if you try to drag by clicking the button placed inside the div ,it will not drag.

Comment: is there any way to just move the button without using any div or panel?

Comment: Sure change the button id to draggable - check the jquery draggable  help modules as well

Comment: i had added this line in the div section---<asp:Button ID="draggable" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" runat="server" Width="50px" Height="50px" />---and in addition i had added <form> section,because i am getting error if i hadnt added the form

Comment: If you are in a form asp.net may well be changing the id of the rendered button using ctl00_ prefix or something similar?  You need to check how the draggable module works with different ids.